# "Template is missing" error using jQuery with Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to add avatars to user profile with a "add user avatar" link in edit account page.

this is avatars_controller.rb:

```
def new
  @avatar = Avatar.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @avatar }
    format.js
  end
end

def create
  @avatar = @user.avatars.create(params[:avatar])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @avatar.save
      format.html { redirect_to(edit_account_path, :notice => 'Avatar was successfully created.') }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @avatar, :status => :created, :location => @avatar }
      format.js
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @avatar.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      format.js
    end
  end
 end
```

this is my link:

```
<%= link_to "add a new avatar", new_avatar_path%>
```

routes:

```
resources :avatars
resources :users do
  resources :avatars
end
```

views/avatars/create.js.erb:

```
alert('whoaaa!!!')
```

i'm using rails 3.0.9 and getting:

**Template is missing**

> Missing template avatars/new with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder,
>   :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths
>   "/home/ugur/rails_projects/deneme/app/views",
>   "/home/ugur/rails_projects/deneme/app/views",
>   "/home/ugur/rails_projects/deneme/flag_promotions/app/views",
>   "/home/ugur/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/spree-0.60.1/app/views",
>   "/home/ugur/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/spree_sample-0.60.1/app/views",
>   "/home/ugur/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/spree_promo-0.60.1/app/views",
>   "/home/ugur/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/spree_dash-0.60.1/app/views",
>   "/home/ugur/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/spree_api-0.60.1/app/views",
>   "/home/ugur/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/spree_auth-0.60.1/app/views",
>   "/home/ugur/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/devise-1.3.3/app/views",
>   "/home/ugur/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/spree_core-0.60.1/app/views"

i'm about to go crazy. please help.

Comment: Do you have a 'edit' method? You link to edit_avatar_path. Not to create_avatar_path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the `edit` action and hoping the `create` template to be rendered. That's the point.

Given your output, I guess the `edit` action is rendering the `new.js.erb` template which doesn't exist.

---

Change:

```
<%= link_to "add a new avatar", new_avatar_path%>
```

with:

```
<%= link_to "add a new avatar", new_avatar_path, :remote => true %>
```

To actually make an ajax request.

---

Se my commit here: https://github.com/apneadiving/avatars/commit/f88ebf3f65e2ad88176cd28f09fd9dc91448cb98

It works at url `/avatars`

Comment: @macfan_: any comment? don't forget to accept an answer if it fits

Comment: sorry i posted wrong link. it is corrected. please have a look.

Comment: Ok but same conclusion: you call the new action so the partial should be new.js.erb

Comment: i aleady did it. i also used avatars/new.js.erb but no use.

Comment: i have both new.js.erb and create.js.erb

Comment: sorry i forgot to change it. i ve already done that but still no use.

Comment: With the few info I've here, no. I could check your code if you give access to your git repo

Comment: git@github.com:ugurigun/avatars.git

Comment: thanks for the answer but the problem is in _user_form.html.erb:       <%= link_to "add a new avatar", new_avatar_path, :remote => true %>

Comment: give me an url, would be easier

Comment: flag_promotions/app/views/shared/_user_form.html.erb

Comment: that's not an url. What do you type in the browser?

Comment: ok, it's due to a bug in rails.js file. See my commit: https://github.com/apneadiving/avatars/commit/54ce555731b89fcb38c748ad47af212fd0abda4f

Comment: oh sorry for being late but it seems rails is having difficulty in processing jquery. i had to remove commented lines because the response won't get processed otherwise. anyways, thank you so much for being interested and a 'well deserved' acceptance! hey people out there, this apneadiving is a great guy!

Comment: :) consider +1 some of my answers when you'll have enough reputation :)